# React SSR + Redux + child components which need to get data from the server

Tags: reactjs, redux, server-side-rendering

I have a React Application CSR (client side rendering) application which i am trying to convert to server side rendering.  I have a query regarding components which need to get additional data from the server.

**Summary of my CSR version**

Tree of components rendered:

```
Home
  |- multiple "ChildItemComponent"
                      |- multiple "GrandChildItemComponent"
                                           |- render elements, such as a img, text etc
```

- "Home" component makes a server call to get a list of parent IDs, then for each ParentId it makes another server call to get the child item and builds an array of all child items. In "render" it maps over the total child items and renders the "ChildItemComponent" for each child

  ```
  componentDidMount() {
    ...
    let totalChildItems = [];

    fetchParentItems()
      .then((parentItems) => {

        parentItems.forEach((parent, index) => {
          fetchChildItems(parent.id)
            .then((childItems) => {
              totalChildItems = totalChildItems.concat(childItems);
            })
            ...
        });
      })
      ....
  }


   render(){
     ....
     {totalChildItems.map(
       (childItem) => <ChildItemComponent key={totalChildItems.id} item={childItem} />,
     )}
     ....
   }
  ```
- In "ChildItemComponent", for each ChildItemId it makes a server call to get Grand Child items. In "render" it maps over the total grandchild items and renders the "GrandChildItemComponent" for each grandchild

  ```
  componentDidMount() {
    ...
    let totalGrandChildren = [];


    childItems.forEach((child, index) => {
      fetchGrandChildren(child.id)
        .then((grandChild) => {
          totalGrandChildren = totalGrandChildren .concat(grandChild);
        })
        ...
    });
  }


   render(){
     ....
     {totalGrandChildren.map(
       (grandChild) => <GrandChildItemComponent key={totalGrandChildren.id} item={grandChild} />,
     )}
     ....
   }
  ```
- in "GrandChildItemComponent" it makes a server call to get additional data for that particular item (for example an image URL), in the "render" method it just renders the item

  ```
  componentDidMount() {           
     getItemImage(grandChild.id)
     .then((url) => {
         // store URL on state
     })
  }

  render(){
    const { url } = this.state;
    ....
    <img ...... />
  }
  ```

As you can see, there are 3 components which all make a server call.

**NextJS**

When I wrote a similar NextJS application, NextJS makes you get all the data upfront in the "page" component, i.e "Home" and the other components just had to receive data.

**React SSR + Redux**

I believe the same is the case when writing plain React SSR (i.e. not using a SSR framework like NextJS). Is this correct?

Looking at all React SSR + Redux examples, they only have getting very simple data (a simple single get request from a server which does not need additional server calls) in the page and any reusable components are just rendering UI.

I am presuming that because components getting data no longer return a component, they can not be added to the JSX in a render method and hence why they can not get data themselves. For example if my "ComponentA" in my ReactSSR app is the following:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { getData } from '../redux/actions';

class ComponentA extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getData();
  }

  render() {
    ....
  }
}

function loadData(store) {
  return store.dispatch(getData());
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { data: state.homePageData };
}

export default {
  loadData,
  component: connect(mapStateToProps, { getData })(ComponentA ),
};
```

Its no longer returning a component, its returning an object containing a function and a component,  therefore surely in another component I can NOT do

```
 import ComponentA from './ComponentA.jsx';
 
 render(){
    <ComponentA />
 }
```

As a result ComponentA can not get data from the server.

**My query/issue**

Am I correct in understanding that I have to get all the data upfront in "Home" page (storing in Redux) and then the other components are just functional components which receive data/get the data from the store.

If this is the case, my server call code gets really complex as i have several server calls each one depending on data from the other which need to be called before the component can be rendered.  This is turning out to be really quite slow.